# Splitting a vector in a dataframe into column vectors

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a vector in a data frame that I want to split into many column vectors as follows:

```
region<- c("US","India", "France", "Greece")
id<- c(1, 2,3,4)
df1<- data.frame(region,id)
```

I want to split the data frame as follows:

```
region.US  region.India region.France region.Greece  id 
  1            0              0            0          1
  0            1              0            0          2
  0            0              1            0          3
  0            0              0            1          4
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To get exactly that output:

```
cbind(setNames(as.data.frame(diag(nrow(df1))), paste0("region.", df1$region)),
      df1[,"id", drop=FALSE])
#   region.US region.India region.France region.Greece id
# 1         1            0             0             0  1
# 2         0            1             0             0  2
# 3         0            0             1             0  3
# 4         0            0             0             1  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this even though it is not exactly what you want.

```
t(table(df1))
   region
id  France Greece India US
  1      0      0     0  1
  2      0      0     1  0
  3      1      0     0  0
  4      0      1     0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

This almost works (the order of columns isn't identical, and the
column names aren't dot-separated):

```
df1 <- data.frame(region=c("US","India", "France", "Greece"),
                 id=1:4)
data.frame(model.matrix(~region-1,df1),id=df1$id)
```